# How to redirect when clicked on Carousel images in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have Carousel installed from 'react-responsive-carousel' npm package. In that I want to redirect to some component on click of images sliding in it. How could be it done

```
const data = [
    {
      img:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/736230/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
    },
    {
      img:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__340.jpg"
    },
    {
      img:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/33/flower-729512__340.jpg"
    },
    {
      img:
        "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/sunflower-1508785046.jpg"
    }
  ];

<Carousel autoPlay infiniteLoop showArrows={false} showThumbs={false}>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <Link to="/images">
              <img src={item.img} />
            </Link>
          ))}
</Carousel>
```

Below is the link for CodeSandbox for better clarity
CodeSandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-sea-1ptl3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally wrapping of your `img` element with `Link` should have worked but on inspecting the css, I noticed that your `Carousal` css , specifically the `.carousal img` selector has the rule `pointer-events:none` and that's why you're not seeing that hand cursor when hovering over the `img` as you generally do.

So you can either add one more layer like that of `div` between `Link` and `img` and that will work.

Or you can override the css of the `Carousal` library that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

add your target URL to your data object, like this:

```
const data = [
    {
      img:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/736230/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
      targetURL: "/posts/blahblah?id=10100110",
    },
       ......]
```

then add onChange props to the image tag and use the `useHistory` to change your route, e.g:

```
const history = useHistory();

<img src={item.img} onChange={() => history.push(item.targetURL)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `Link` by `div` and use `onClick()` on this tag

```
{data.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              onClick={() => window.open("https://javascript.info/")}
            >
              <img src={item.img} alt="img" />
            </div>
          ))}
```

Comment: OK... Can't we use <Link/> ? because that would be much beneficial

Answer (score 0):

````
    {
      id:1,
      img:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/736230/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      img:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__340.jpg"
    },
    {
      id:3,
      img:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/33/flower-729512__340.jpg"
    },
    {
      id:4,
      img:
        "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/sunflower-1508785046.jpg"
    }
  ];

<Carousel autoPlay infiniteLoop showArrows={false} showThumbs={false}>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <Link to=`/images/${item.id}`>
              //change <Route /> in App.js accordingly
              <img src={item.img} />
            </Link>
          ))}
</Carousel>```
````

Comment: If you don't mind can you make changes in my CodesandBox

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` tag generated from `<Link>` is there it's just that it's about 20px high.

I'm not sure what css the carousel generates but I suggest diving in and seeing if you can absolute position the `<a>` tag and take 100% width and height - to a parent that has position relative ofcourse.